# Почему не воспроизводится видео? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

В гугле нашёл инфу что проблема связана с FFmpeg, да и моё подозрение тоже на него начинает падать. Вот фрагмент с ним (с радостью оставил бы весь код, но сайт не позволяет :( )

собсна фрагмент -

```py
async def play_music(ctx, url):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice is None:
        voice = await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await voice.move_to(voice_channel)

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 1`
```

сама ошибка:

```
[out#0/s16le @ 0000027ad0ebac00] Output file does not contain any stream
Error opening output file pipe:1.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument
```

ffmpeg свежей версии, в PATH добавлен, код лежит в той же папке где и ffmpeg (именно exe-шник).
если поставить True вместо False в строке `info = ydl.extract_info(query, download=False)`, то видео просто будет скачиваться в папку с кодом, что вполне ожидаемо, но проблема не решается таким методом.